# Normalize / Transform all Panels in a Dashboard in Grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb, grafana-variable, grafana-templating

I have a Grafana Dashboard with a bunch of panels of time series data - for example, some graphs of "number of searches" this week vs last week at the same time, grouped by time.

I want to normalize this data by, say, number of new users, so the search volume week over week takes into account how busy that week was.

I can do this by manually adding 2 additional queries to a panel that retrieves from InfluxDB the number of Users Created grouped in the same time series, then applying a Transform in that panel.

However, I'd like to be able to apply and unapply this - "Normalize By UserCreation" to all the panels in the dashboard - Ad Hoc filters seem close - but not configurable enough for what I want.

What's the best way to accomplish what I'm looking for?